# How to debug on TypeScript code instead of JavaScript code in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm

How to debug on TypeScript code instead of JavaScript code in Chrome?

I only found a way to do that manually every time from the start. I write code in Angular2 with WebStorm 11.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug angular app using angular-cli webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348213/how-to-debug-angular-app-using-angular-cli-webpack)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adrian said your transpiler needs to produce map info, which can also be generated into the js output file instead of a separate .map file.

One issue you may run into is that within lambda functions (aka arrow functions) you will not be able to see your variables, neither in chrome  nor in WebStorm.
However, there is a setting in WebStorm that allows you to see your `this.` variables properly within the WebStorm debugger:

Goto `Help`, `Find Action`, enter "registry".
In the registry check `js.debugger.map.this.by.source.code`

Answer (score 5):

You need to have your transpiler generate .map files.