# What makes it possible to debug typescript in chrome?

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript

What  makes it possible to debug typescript in chrome when browser understands only Javascript? I always debug my typescript files in my angular project created using angular CLI from chrome developers tool, however I don't know the reason how we are able to debug typescript files. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Learn about source maps and transpilation.

Comment: Please refer to this answer:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/51443584/6923507

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714537/chrome-debug-angular-typescript-how-to-navigate-to-ts-file/51941277#51941277

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Angular CLI uses webpack.  When webpack transpiles your TS to JS, it can be be configured (and is by default) to generate source maps as well.  This is how Chrome is able to tie the javascript code back to typescript for debugging.

Example **tsconfig.json** generated by angular CLI:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true, <--- this right here
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```