# How does one set IntelliJ breakpoints in Angular HTML files?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

In chrome it's possible to set breakpoints in the Angular component html files. How does one do this in IntelliJ?

Please note that following other posts about how to configure IntelliJ to debug Angular do not address this question, I can debug .ts files just fine, but IntelliJ does not let you set breakpoints in html files even with the webpack source mapping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to debug angular app using angular-cli webpack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39348213/608639)

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. IntelliJ still won't let you set breakpoints in the html using the settings in that other post, Chrome does.